# Get a Shell to running container inside "Traefik" Pod on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

We tried attaching a shell to container inside "Traefik" Pod using following command but it didn't work. Just FYI, we used helm chart to install Traefik on our k8s cluster.

`kubectl exec -it <traefik Pod name> -- /bin/sh`

tried this too but no success -  `kubectl exec -it <traefik Pod name> -- /bin/bash`

Any help in this context will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any error message that you got?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to go inside `traefik` pod? Maybe outcome you want to achieve can be done by other measures.

Comment: @DawidKruk, We deployed PEGA CRM platform on k8s. Worker nodes use GMT timezone but there was a requirement to update the timezone to CST on pega related JVMs. We did that and when we launched the portal directly using Pod IP (they are routable at the moment) it's working fine.. But when we go via. Traefik (acting as Ingress controller in cluster), it's taking GMT timezone.. So we just wanted to attach a shell to traefik pod to change the timezone manually and see how it reflects in reports afterwards..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traefik 1.7 uses a [`FROM scratch`](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/Dockerfile) container image that has only the Traefik executable and some support files. There is no shell. You would have to switch to the `-alpine` variant of the image. For 2.x it looks like they use Alpine by default for some reason.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger. I'll try with 2.x and let you know the outcome.

Comment: I tried and am getting following error - "command traefik error: field not found, node: compress"

Comment: Tried with following image traefik:v1.7.20-alpine and it worked for us.. We were able to attach a shell to running container in traefik pod.

Comment: I should add that changing the timezone files interactively will probably have no effect, so this was all for nothing. As mentioned below, you can set timezones in your containers by using hostPath mounts.

Comment: we wanted a different timezone in traefik container comapred to host(worker node) running that container. I found a solution.. and that is to set the env variable in Traefil helm chart "Values.yaml" file.. and it worked perfectly fine..

Comment: Slight diversion: I came to this juncture because I needed to see the logs. Instead of trying to get a whole shell working, access to logs might suffice. This worked for me: `docker-compose logs traefik > logfile.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time zone by mounting volume

```
volumes:
- "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
- "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
```

Ref: https://bobcares.com/blog/change-time-in-docker-container/